# spark 2.0 read csv with json

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
"a","b","c","{""x"":""xx"",""y"":""yy""}"
```

When I use java CSV reader (`au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser`), it manages to parse the string when I indicate `defaultEscapeChar = '\u0000'`

When I tried to read it with spark 2.2 CSV reader, it failed and wasn't able to split it to 4 columns. This is what I tried:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
              .option("quoteMode","ALL")
              .option("quote", "\u0000")
              .load("s3://...")
```

I also tries it with `option("escape", "\u0000")`
but with no luck.

Which CSV options I need to choose in order to parse this file correctly?

Comment: perhaps save it as .json?

Comment: `{""x"":""xx"",""y"":""yy""}` should be stored in the last column ?

Comment: the data is in csv format the json in only one column,
once I extract the json from the csv I will parse it

Comment: @philantrovert it must be in the last column due to compatible reasons

Comment: You don't need to escape the quote I think. Remove `quote` as well.

Answer (score 8):

You actually were close, right option is `option("escape", "\"")`
so given recent spark version (2.2+ or maybe even earlier), snippet below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

object CsvJsonMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CsvJsonExample").master("local").getOrCreate()

    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
    val csvData: Dataset[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
      """
        |"a","b","c","{""x"":""xx"",""y"":""yy""}"
      """.stripMargin)).toDS()

    val frame = spark.read.option("escape", "\"").csv(csvData)
    frame.show()
  }
}
```

would produce

```
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|                _c3|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|  a|  b|  c|{"x":"xx","y":"yy"}|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
```

The reason why spark fails to parse such csv out-of-the box is that default escape value is '\' symbol as could be seen on the line 91 at [CSVOptions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVOptions.scala) and it's obviously wouldn't work with default json quotes escaping.

The underlying reason why it used to work before spark 2.0 with databricks-csv library is that underlying csv engine used to be [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) and escape character defaulted to null would allow library to detect json and it's way of escaping. Since 2.0 csv functionality is part of the spark itself and using [uniVocity CSV parser](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) which doesn't provide such "magic" but apparently is faster.

P.S. Don't forget to specify escaping when writing csv files, if you want to preserve json data as it is.

```
frame.write.option("quoteAll","true").option("escape", "\"").csv("csvFileName")
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm on Spark 1.6 and using Spark CSV as an external JAR but this works for me:

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
          .option("quoteMode", "ALL")
          .option("delimiter", ",")
          .load("file")
          .show

+---+---+---+-------------------+
| C0| C1| C2|                 C3|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|  a|  b|  c|{"x":"xx","y":"yy"}|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
```

EDIT : Looks like Spark CSV is intelligent enough

```
sc.textFile("file").collect
res7: Array[String] = Array(a,b,c,"{""x"":""xx"",""y"":""yy""}")

scala> sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load("file").show
+---+---+---+-------------------+
| C0| C1| C2|                 C3|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|  a|  b|  c|{"x":"xx","y":"yy"}|
+---+---+---+-------------------+


scala> sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quoteMode", "ALL").load("file").show
+---+---+---+-------------------+
| C0| C1| C2|                 C3|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|  a|  b|  c|{"x":"xx","y":"yy"}|
+---+---+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, it should. Works for me.

Comment: @philantrovert, why are you still in 1.6? I thought you already upgraded. :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have Spark 2 at home. Stuck with 1.6 at work :D

Comment: this is what I'm getting with spark 2.1:

```spark.sqlContext.read.format("csv").load("/tmp/test.csv").show
+---+---+---+--------------+---------------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|           _c3|            _c4|
+---+---+---+--------------+---------------+
|  a|  b|  c|"{""x"":""xx""|""y"":""yy""}""|
+---+---+---+--------------+---------------+```

Comment: Okay that's fine but as per your question the data contains quotes so you should be using `quoteMode` set to `ALL` and you should be good.