# How to convert JSON string with "" (instead of ") to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, csv, string-parsing, spark-csv

I have a string:

```
a = '"{""key1"": ""val1"", ""key2"":""val2""}"'
```

What is the most propriate way to convert this to a dictionary in Python?

plain `json.loads(a)` cannot decipher this format.

**EDIT:**
This weird JSON string is created when I read a CSV with one "json-like" column.

Comment: Where does it come from? A CSV?

Comment: @chepner - oh, sorry, that was a typo

Comment: @Ry- yes, it does - good catch :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the string came from a CSV file, use `csv` to decode it before passing the result to `json` for decoding.

```
>>> import io, csv, json
>>> a = '"{""key1"": ""val1"", ""key2"":""val2""}"'
>>> csv_file_like = io.StringIO(a)
>>> reader = csv.reader(csv_file_like)
>>> result = list(reader)
>>> json.loads(result[0][0])
{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
```

This is a little simpler if `a` was already set by reading from a CSV file; you can skip using `io` to create a file-like object from `a` and use `csv.reader` directly on the original CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this kind of format for json. So you can use the next function :

```
import json
def load_weird_json(json_string):
    a = json_string.replace('""','"')
    a = a[1:len(a)-1]
    return json.loads(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import json
a = '"{""key1"": ""val1"", ""key2"":"val2""}"'
a = a.replace('""','"').replace('}"',"}").replace('"{','{')
data = json.loads(a)
print(data)
```

output

```
{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The @chepner's answer actually sent me in the right direction. The string was loaded from CSV and I could effectively prevent this weird JSON forming by using answer from here: [spark 2.0 read csv with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176021/spark-2-0-read-csv-with-json), i.e. add the escape char `'\"'` option.

Thanks for the answers - they all work :)